# css transform is not working correctly with firefox

Tags: css

on my website https://koengeter-immobilien.de i have a centered logo with a shrinked header. I centered the logo with the css command

```
.html_header_top.html_logo_center .logo {
    transform: translate(-63%, -2%); }
```

It works fine in Google Chome and IE. But in firefox the logo is above the menu when the the website is scrolled.

I cant find a solution for firefox.

Can somebody help?

best regards

Comment: Please read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your post.

Comment: thanks... i edited...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div menu must be positioned absolute:

```
#header_main_alternate {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you inspect the code you can see the 2 divs stay one over the other.